# RegEx to replace string only if it is not value of attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace the price in JavaScript string, but only if it is not a value of an attribute. The result should look like this:

```
'<span title="$30,000,000.50">$30,000,000.50</span>' // original
'<span title="$30,000,000.50">xxx</span>' // desired result

'bla bla bla $30,000,000.50 bla bla bla' // original
'bla bla bla xxx bla bla bla' // desired result
```

I define the price as a dollar sign, followed by a combination of digits, dots and commas:

```
/\$[\d,.]+/
```

That works fine. But when I try to exclude the occurences where this pattern is wrapped in quotes, it starts to behave funny:

```
'<span title="$30,000,000.50">$30,000,000.50</span>'.replace(/(?!=\")(\$[\d,.]+)(?!\")/gi, 'xxx');
// <span title="xxx0">xxx</span>
```

Notice that it replaced the value of title attribute, but it kept the last zero.

Can you please correct my code and tell me what I do wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it won't be easier and more readable to use actual code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a negative look ahead and a negative look behind. Unfortunately, JavaScript doesn't support look behinds. However, using a technique from: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript you can mimic this behavior.

```
str.replace(/(\")?(\$[\d,.]+)(?!\")/gi, function ($0, $1) {
    return $1 ? $0 : 'xxx';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nachito/Wfdq6/1/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript haves the powerful feature of using functions to make replacements, use it:

```
'<a title="$30">$30</a>'.replace(/\$[^<>]*?(<|$)/g,function($0){return $0.replace("$","")})
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simplify and make the markup tags part of the regex

```
var str = '<span title="$30,000,000.50">$30,000,000.50</span>';
var newStr = str.replace(/>\$[\d,.]+</gi, '>xxx<');

//prints -> <span title="$30,000,000.50">xxx</span>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KPTD8/)

Comment: +1 - that's what I was thinking, but couldn't work it out. http://jsfiddle.net/9pUE3/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, this works only if the price is inside tag. It won't work in cases like this: "bla bla bla $30,000,000.50 bla bla bla" I'm sorry I didn't mention it in the original post. I have updated it to make it more clear.